# Session ID change with every load inside iFrame when disabled Third-party cookies in the browser

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

I am searching for answers across Internet, but most of the answers are old that does not work anymore or they involve changing the host and the remove server. I want a solution where I can give a working iframe html code to my clients and they can embedded it into their website's and use the build-in shop from my website into their website. The website opens successfully, but the session changes every time there is a new request. I tried put this on my server end, but this is not working

```
session_set_cookie_params(["SameSite" => "None"]); //none, lax, strict
session_set_cookie_params(["Secure" => "true"]); //false, true
session_set_cookie_params(["HttpOnly" => "true"]); //false, true
```

I am open to idea's for my problem. After a lot of digging I can see that Chrome changed something and now you can't have persist session from one site to other, because of hacking attacks I guess.

Is there a way to keep the session between pages in Chrome 106 and above is my question without changing anything to the remote server website?

**Update:** @Cbroe is right this is happening probably because I disabled the Third-party cookies in my browser, but is someone give me a working solution to that I will be more then glad or if there is a working solution to that at all or I have to change my code and send the session with GET/POST requests like CBroe is suggesting.

Comment: Not _hacking_, but (user) _tracking_. Third-party cookies will likely get blocked more and more in the future. One option to avoid that would be to switch to transporting the session ID via GET/POST, instead of cookies. (Whether the security "trade-offs" that comes with are acceptable for your use case, you'll have to determine yourself.)

Comment: @CBroe, you are actually right it is because of blocking the Third-party cookies.

Comment: There is no "solution" to using 3rd-party cookies when 3rd-party cookies are disabled in the browser. It would be ridiculous, if _you_ could do anything from your end, to override the user's choice in that regard (because if _you_ could, all the bad tracker people would use the same technique, thereby making this setting worthless.)

Comment: But PHP _can_ automatically append the session ID parameter to links and add it into forms, using the "transparent sid support" feature, https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid

Comment: Thanks CBroe I will try that. My question was more like, what is the best "solution" in those cases. I know a user can stop the third-party cookies, but I also know that probably in the feature they will be disabled by default so I was just wondering what that will mean for all iframe sites using sessions - like mine.